# How to compile a self created Apache module under windows in repeatable batch mode?

Tags: c, apache-modules

How to compile a self created Apache module under windows in repeatable batch mode (without using a tool that I have to compile with a tool that I have to compile first)?

I have got:

- win 10 / german
- visual studio build tools 2017 (as I have read somewhere that apache win is compiled via visual studio's cl)
- apache 2.24 - compiled for 64-Bit
- a demo apache module code 'mod_example_1.c' from here: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/developer/modguide.html

here is what I did:

- tried to recompile aspx -> got stuck in perl error message -> gave up on this as learning perl seems to me like a one way into nowhere
- found out, that windows apache is compiled via visual studio
- tried to run:

[mypath]\cl -nologo -MD -W3 -O2 -c -DWIN32 -D_WINDOWS -DNDEBUG
   -I[includepath1] -I[includepath2] -I[includepath3] -I[includepath4] -I[includepath5] mod_example_1.c

from within the path where I put mod_example_1.c, according to post 2 under

https://www.apachelounge.com/viewtopic.php?t=5611

(of cause bracket-strings [ ] are placeholders for real pathes or pathes+files on my computer)

This returned me german error messages:

```
mod_example_1.c(13): error C2054: Nach "module" muss "(" folgen
mod_example_1.c(13): error C2085: "example_module": Nicht in der formalen Parameterliste enthalten
mod_example_1.c(13): error C2143: Syntaxfehler: Es fehlt ";" vor "="
mod_example_1.c(30): warning C4013: "ap_hook_handler" undefiniert; Annahme: extern mit Rückgabetyp int
```

meaning:

```
mod_example_1.c(13): error C2054: "module" requires to be succeeded by "("
mod_example_1.c(13): error C2085: "example_module": Not part of the formal list of parameters
mod_example_1.c(13): error C2143: Syntaxfehler: ";" is missing, before "="
mod_example_1.c(30): warning C4013: "ap_hook_handler" undefined; assumption: external with return type int
```

I would think, that a missing capability in cl to parse the term 'module' indicates that cl cannot be used to compile apache-webserver-modules. However why is that guy from the other forum writing, it works like this? What do I miss?

Comment: Note: the apachelounge link is for building on an apache 2.4 version, whereas you say you are building on an apache 2.24 (which I take you mean 2.2.24)... different versions may have different build instructions.

Comment: thank you, TonyB - point taken; I still wonder if the error does not indicate a(nother) more substantial issue; also in the meantime I found other similar compile statements for g++ and gcc (which target apache versionss before 2.4 and which indicate that the same or similar compile patterns work there as well). I am fittling with cygwin in parallel - let's see, where this goes

Answer (score 0):

There is an oddball apxs-for-windows available with mod_perl:

http://www.apache.org/dist/perl/win32-bin/